# Enviar formato date javascript via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou tentando enviar dados de um formulário de cadastro via Ajax/javascript para um serviço java, porém o banco recebe os dados no formato date e não sei o que devo fazer para converter para date, como faço para realizar esta conversão?

```
function consumir() {

  $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "http://dalvz/core-web/rest/usuarios",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    cache: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({
      "nome": document.getElementById('nome').value,
      "sobrenome": document.getElementById('sobrenome').value,
      "dataNascimento": document.getElementById('dataNascimento').value,
      "email": document.getElementById('email').value,
      "senha": document.getElementById('senha').value
    }),

    success: function (data) {
      alert(data.nome);
    }

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso você tenha que entregar esta data no formato YYYY-MM-DD e tenha ela no formato DD/MM/YYYY , você pode utilizar este código para converter.

```
var dataNascimento = new Date(document.getElementById('dataNascimento').substr(0, 10).split('/').reverse().join('-'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você está usando a data em formado "d/m/A", para inserir no banco de dados Mysql ela deve estar em "Y/m/d".

O seu código deve ficar assim:

```
function consumir() {

    var data = document.getElementById('dataNascimento').value.split("-");
    var dataNascimento = new Date(data[2], data[1], data[0]);

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "http://dalvz/core-web/rest/usuarios",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "nome": document.getElementById('nome').value,
            "sobrenome": document.getElementById('sobrenome').value,
            "dataNascimento": dataNascimento,
            "email": document.getElementById('email').value,
            "senha": document.getElementById('senha').value
        }),

        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.nome);
        }

    });
}
```